# How to refer to the root of the tail of a path in a zsh command?

Tags: zsh

I often clone a git repository then enter its root directory. For example:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/hpjansson/chafa && cd chafa
```

To make this a little easier, I have a zsh abbreviation – `cc` – which is expanded into `&& cd !#:2:t`:

```
typeset -Ag abbrev
abbrev=(
  'G' '| grep -v grep | grep'
  'L' '2>&1 | less'
  'V' '2>&1 | vipe >/dev/null'
  'ac' '| column -t'
  'bl' '; tput bel'
  'cc' '&& cd !#:2:t'
  'fl' "| awk '{ print $"
  'ne' '2>/dev/null'
  'pf' "printf -- '"
  'sl' '>/dev/null 2>&1'
  'tl' '| tail -20'
)
__abbrev_expand() {
  emulate -L zsh
  setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
  local MATCH
  LBUFFER=${LBUFFER%%(#m)[a-zA-Z]#}
  if [[ "${LBUFFER: -1}" == ' ' ]]; then
    LBUFFER+=${abbrev[$MATCH]:-$MATCH}
    if [[ $MATCH = 'fl' ]]; then
      RBUFFER="}'"
    elif [[ $MATCH = 'pf' ]]; then
      RBUFFER="\n'"
    fi
  else
    LBUFFER+=$MATCH
  fi
  zle self-insert
}
zle -N __abbrev_expand
bindkey ' ' __abbrev_expand
bindkey -M isearch ' ' self-insert
```

`!#` refers to the current command-line, as described in `man zshexpn` (section `HISTORY EXPANSION`, subsection `Event Designators`):

> `!#`     Refer to the current command line typed in so far.  The line  is
>          treated  as  if  it  were  complete up to and including the word
>          before the one with the `!#` reference.

`:2` refers to the second word on the command-line (which is the url when I type a `$ git clone` command):

> `n`      The nth argument.

And `:t` refers to the tail of that word:

> `t`      Remove  all leading pathname components, leaving the tail.  This
>           works like `basename`.

---

Typically, I will type `git clone` on the command-line, then copy-paste the url of the project, then insert a space, `cc` and another space, which gives the desired command.

However, sometimes, the url that I copy-paste ends with the extension `.git`. When that happens the expansion of `!#:2:t` contains an undesirable `.git` extension:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/hpjansson/chafa.git cc
→
$ git clone https://github.com/hpjansson/chafa.git && cd !#:2:t
→
$ git clone https://github.com/hpjansson/chafa.git && cd chafa.git
cd: no such file or directory: chafa.git
```

One solution is to also use the `:r` modifier to remove the `.git` extension:

> `r`      Remove a filename extension leaving the root name.  Strings with
>          no  filename extension are not altered.  A filename extension is
>          a `.` followed by any number of characters (including zero) that
>          are  neither  `.`  nor  `/`  and that continue to the end of the
>          string.  For example, the extension of `foo.orig.c` is `.c`, and
>          `dir.c/foo` has no extension.

```
                                                               vv
$ git clone https://github.com/hpjansson/chafa.git && cd !#:2:t:r
→
$ git clone https://github.com/hpjansson/chafa.git && cd chafa
```

However, if the path does not end with a `.git` extension, then the expansion fails and neither the `git` command nor the `cd` command is executed.

Here is a minimal example to illustrate the issue:

```
$ echo /foo/bar.baz !#:1:t:r
/foo/bar.baz bar

$ echo /foo/bar !#:1:t:r
zsh: modifier failed: r
```

The first command succeeds, because the last path component contains the extension `.baz`, but the second one fails because there is no extension anymore. OTOH, in bash `4.3.48`, both commands work as expected.

I don't understand why `:r` fails when there is no extension, because its documentation contains this sentence:

> Strings with no filename extension are not altered.

It doesn't say that using `:r` for a string which doesn't contain an extension is an error.

---

I tried another approach; removing the extension with the `:s` modifier. I think this requires the `HIST_SUBST_PATTERN` option to be set:

```
setopt HIST_SUBST_PATTERN
```

With this option, one can write `:s/.*` to remove an extension:

```
                          vvvvv
$ echo /foo/bar.baz !#:1:t:s/.*
/foo/bar.baz bar
```

It works when there is an extension, but again fails when there is none:

```
$ setopt HIST_SUBST_PATTERN
$ echo /foo/bar !#:1:t:s/.*
zsh: substitution failed
```

---

Is there a single sequence of modifiers which can simultaneously refer to `bar` in `/foo/bar.baz`, and to `bar` in `/foo/bar`?

I'm using `zsh 5.7.1-dev-0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this with history expansion. But I don't think history expansion is the best tool here. It's very limited. From a [zle widget](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#User_002dDefined-Widgets), you can access the command line and manipulate it with arbitrary code. Take advantage of this.

One approach would be to do expansion on the abbreviation: instead of `$abbrev[$MATCH]`, use `${(e)abbrev[$MATCH]}`. Obviously you'll need to change your abbreviations to quote special characters appropriately. For `cc`, use something like

```
&& cd ${${(z)BUFFER}[3]}
```

---

For the specific case of `git clone`, and more generally for anything that creates a directory in the current directory, you could use a different abbreviation: switch to the newly created directory. That works with `git clone https://example.com/foo.git`, for `git clone https://example.com/foo`, and for `git clone https://example.com/foo.git bar`, as well as for `tar xf foo.tar` (if the archive has a single toplevel directory) and `mv /some/directory .`.

```
&& cd *(/oc[1])
```